# Newtonsoft - Mapping json into .NET Classes

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a json feed that can be seen [here](http://www.ticketfly.com/api/events/upcoming.json?orgId=1&pageNum=21&fieldGroup=light&fields=dateCreated,featured,published,publishDate,image,onSaleDate,offSaleDate,promoterName,sponsorName,sponsorImage,additionalInfo,showTypeCode,showType,externalTicketingUrls,facebookEventId,isMobileFriendly,isMobileFriendlyBoolean,headliners.id,headliners.name,headliners.startTime,headliners.eventDescription,headliners.urlOfficialWebsite,headliners.urlMySpace,headliners.urlFacebook,headliners.urlTwitter,headliners.urlAudio,headliners.urlPurchaseMusic,headliners.embedAudio,headliners.embedVideo,headliners.image.original,headliners.image.xlarge,headliners.image.large,headliners.image.medium,headliners.image.small,headliners.image.xlarge1,headliners.image.large1,headliners.image.medium1,headliners.image.small1,headliners.image.square,headliners.image.squareSmall,supports.id,supports.name,supports.startTime,supports.eventDescription,supports.urlOfficialWebsite,supports.urlMySpace,supports.urlFacebook,supports.urlTwitter,supports.urlAudio,supports.urlPurchaseMusic,supports.embedAudio,supports.embedVideo,supports.image.original,supports.image.xlarge,supports.image.large,supports.image.medium,supports.image.small,supports.image.xlarge1,supports.image.large1,supports.image.medium1,supports.image.small1,supports.image.square,supports.image.squareSmall,org.id,org.name,org.timeZone,org.promoter,venue.timeZone,venue.address1,venue.address2,venue.city,venue.stateProvince,venue.postalCode,venue.metroCode,venue.country,venue.url,venue.blurb,venue.urlFacebook,venue.urlTwitter,venue.lat,venue.lng,venue.image,urlEventDetailsUrl).

I properly mapped the enitre json into classes by defining each structure. Just stuck at one place. If you see the json and search for the property `headliners` which is an array, it has a property `image` which is an object. So I created a classes to map

```
 public class HeadeLiners
    {
      public Image Image { get; set; }
    }

 public class Image
    {
      public ImageSize Jumbo{ get; set; }
    }

public class ImageSize 
    {
      public string Path{ get; set; }
      public int Width{ get; set; }
      public int Height{ get; set; }
    }
```

But what happen if in response `headliners` property there is no image found it returns an array which breaks the mapping. and it make sense. I am not sure how to handle this, any please suggest

Comment: It would be nice if you provided a reduced test case of the above feed, so that we could better follow.

Comment: What is the array it returns? Images?

Comment: an empty array otherwise it returns an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, that is one weird use of JSON.

Here's what you can do:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

settings.Error += (obj, errorArgs) =>
{
    if ("image".Equals(errorArgs.ErrorContext.Member))
    {
        errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;                    
    }
};

var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json, settings);
```

By handling the `Error` event, you can selectively ignore these kinds of errors. If you ignore this error at this particular location (checking just the member name might just do it) your `Image` property remains `null`, which is probably what you want here.